# color picker to text schema

Tags: json, schema, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to add a color picker to a change the color of a heading but I can't workout how to add a relation between heading and color picker.

this currently doesn't save as its not valid Json, but this is what I've added to the sections > hero.liquid file

```
  {
    "type": "text",
    "id": "title",
    "label": "Heading",
    "default": "Image with text overlay"
    "settings": [
     {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "color_title",
      "label": "Heading color",
      "default": "#FFFFFF"
     }      
    ]
  },
```

If i include the color picker external to the settings it shows but has no relation to any elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't create the relationship in the schema but in the liquid itself.

The correct syntax is:

```
{
  "type": "text",
  "id": "title",
  "label": "Heading",
  "default": "Image with text overlay"
},
{
  "type": "color",
  "id": "color_title",
  "label": "Heading color",
  "default": "#FFFFFF"
}
```

Then you can do something like:

`<h2 style="color: {{settings.color_title}}">{{ settings.title }}</h2>`

Comment: the color picker shows up but its still not interacting  with the h2

Comment: I'm really new to Shopify so could have missed a simple step

Comment: got it, just had to be  '  style="color: {{section.settings.color_title}}"  '

Comment: @crffty yep. I didn't see that you mentioned that you were in a section.

Answer (score 1):

```
 "settings": [ {
   "type": "color",
   "id": "user_color",
   "label": "Color",
   "default": "#000"
 },
]
```

Then outside the schema tag, to output the color to shopify:

```html
<h2 style="color: {{ section.settings.user_color }}">Kols might be the king</h2>
```

`user_color` being the `id` of the color picker.
This syntax outputs `Kols might be the king` text in black, which is the default color in the schema settings.